# Expression must be a list type: AccountHistory

Tags: accounthistory

Does anybody see what is the mistake in this snippet of code?

```
List <AccountHistory> accHistory = [SELECT Id, Account.name, Field, OldValue, NewValue 
                                    FROM AccountHistory                                                                                                                              
                                    WHERE AccountId = 'asada978asd'                                                                                                                                  
                                    AND field ='Primary_Phone__c'];

List<AccountHistory> accHistList = new List<AccountHistory>();

if(accHistory.size() > 0) {
   for( AccountHistory accHis : accHistory){
      accHistList.add(accHis[0].NewValue);          
   }
}
```

When I try to run it I get this error:

```
"compileProblem": "Expression must be a list type: AccountHistory",
  "compiled": "false",
  "exceptionMessage": "",
  "exceptionStackTrace": "",
```

What I am trying to do here is I try to grab all values of phone that were changing
through the history, put them into list, sort that list and then to be able to say *"Ok I want to grab only last and before last value"*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this fragment...

```
for( AccountHistory accHis : accHistory){
   accHistList.add(accHis[0].NewValue);          
}
```

`accHis` is a single instance of `AccountHistory`, so you can't use the array index notation there.

Additionally, since `accHistList` is a `List<AccountHistory>`, trying to add a string (`accHis.newValue`) to it would also generate an error.

If you're simply looking to add data to a list, there's no need for a loop. `secondList.addAll(firstList);` is all you really need (provided the lists are of compatibble types).

If you really are looking to extract a field value from each record, then a loop is necessary. You'd need to change the list type of `accHistList` to be something appropriate (like `List<String>`), and the check for `accHistory.size() > 0` is not required.

Comment: Great, thanks for your answer. It works now and this is how my code looks now. I applied changes per your suggestion and this is how it looks like now:

`List<String> accHistList = new List<String>();
  
for(AccountHistory accHis : accHistory){
    accHistList.add((String)accHis.NewValue);   
}`